# Organise displayed mysql data in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Can someone please help me organise my displayed data in php using the mysql?

My code

```
<center>
<?php
$db_host = '';
$db_user = '';
$db_pwd = '';

$database = '';
$table = 'pkers';

if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
    die("Can't connect to database");

if (!mysql_select_db($database))
    die("Can't select database");

// sending query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table} ORDER BY points DESC");
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
} 

$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);
echo '<br>';

// printing table headers
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{
    $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
    echo "{$field->points}";
}
// printing table rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{    
    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
     foreach($row as $cell)

// printing table headers
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)

// printing table rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{  
    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
    foreach($row as $cell)
        echo "$cell";
}
}    
?></center>
```

My result shows this

[image]

I would like it to have a break before the next cell is displayed for an example,

```
TOP PKERS:

DANNY    1

USERNAME    0
```

if anyone can help it will be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `<br />` in outer loop.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
    foreach($row as $cell)
        echo " $cell ";

    echo "<br />";
}
```

Alternatively you can use `<table>` layout for a better view.

Answer (score 1):

change the below code:

```
foreach($row as $cell)
    echo "$cell";
```

with

```
foreach($row as $cell)
    echo "$cell ";
echo "<br/>";
```

It will output as you want.

Comment: This will add a new line after each cell, And he wants it to be after each row.